# Error when running npm run build:program-rust on helloworld example

Tags: build-bpf

I'm new to solana developing and am trying to run the hello world example. I am getting the following error after running `npm run build:program-rust` and am not sure how to fix it. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

```
example-helloworld$ npm run build:program-rust

> helloworld@0.0.1 build:program-rust
> cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program

Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /home/<account>/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --sbf-out-dir=dist/program --arch bpf
/home/<account>/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried clearing my solana cache and have reinstalled WSL to try and make sure everything was set up properly.

Comment: Is your wsl distribution a Ubuntu 22.04? Check this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) out anyways and see if it helps

Comment: @Ademola Yes, my distribution is 22.04. I cleared my cache like that post suggested and re-ran the npm run command but ended up getting the same issue. It loaded something for a bit and then gave me the same error saying that it can't find the libssl.so.1.1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found thanks to @Ademola. The linked stackoverflow issue has the solution but doesn't work because a new version of the files mentioned need to be installed.

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb
```

The difference from these commands and the ones in the post is that the version was updated from 16 to 17. If these don't work in the future go to [this link](http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/) and ctrl-f the name of the file you need to see the version currently available.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, you may need to install additional dependencies if cargo install fails

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev libssl-dev
```